# why this Apply template was not working properly

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

if suppose my database having three row records by fetching that data i am converting into xml data as shown below :

Here is my XML:

```
<NewDataSet>
 <Table>
<RECORD_TYPE_CODE>CTD</RECORD_TYPE_CODE>
<MSG_TYPE_CODE>O103N</MSG_TYPE_CODE>
<CTD_SEQ_NUM>000086</CTD_SEQ_NUM>   
<CTD_CTD_PKG_ID>2</CTD_CTD_PKG_ID>
</Table>
<Table>
<RECORD_TYPE_CODE>CTO</RECORD_TYPE_CODE>
<MSG_TYPE_CODE>O203N</MSG_TYPE_CODE>
<CTD_SEQ_NUM>000087</CTD_SEQ_NUM>   
<CTD_CTD_PKG_ID>2</CTD_CTD_PKG_ID>
</Table>
<Table>
<RECORD_TYPE_CODE>CTH</RECORD_TYPE_CODE>
<MSG_TYPE_CODE>O303N</MSG_TYPE_CODE>
<CTD_SEQ_NUM>000088</CTD_SEQ_NUM>   
<CTD_CTD_PKG_ID>2</CTD_CTD_PKG_ID>   
</Table>
</NewDataSet>
```

through c sharp code behind using for loop i m sending package id (CTD_CTD_PKG_ID)and Sequencenum(CTD_SEQ_NUM) through xslt argument parameters it was passing properly in a sequential order like 000086,000087,000088 but first time for in aloop i will pass 000086 seqnum it was fetching proper manner next when i m passing 000087 it was generating data in table of 000086 only why it was happening passing parameter value is goin good in a sequential order

here is my XSLT:

```
    <xsl:param name="PackageId"  />
<xsl:param name="SequenceNum"  />
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:apply-templates mode="SequenceB"  select="(NewDataSet/Table[CTD_CTD_PKG_ID =$PackageId]    |   NewDataSet/Table[CTD_SEQ_NUM =$SequenceNum])[1]"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess (if my guess is incorrect, you need to explain better the problem) that the value of your `$PackageId` parameter is always defined as `2`.

The XPath expression you are using:

```
    (NewDataSet/Table[CTD_CTD_PKG_ID =$PackageId]
   |
     NewDataSet/Table[CTD_SEQ_NUM =$SequenceNum]
     )
     [1]
```

selects the first node from the union of the nodes selected by:

```
NewDataSet/Table[CTD_CTD_PKG_ID =$PackageId]
```

and:

```
NewDataSet/Table[CTD_SEQ_NUM =$SequenceNum]
```

**Do note**, that if the value of the `$PackageId` parameter is `2`, then the first node of theis union is always `/*/Table[1]`.

**The solution is to replace the XPath expression you are using with**:

```
NewDataSet/Table[CTD_CTD_PKG_ID =$PackageId][CTD_SEQ_NUM =$SequenceNum]
```

Comment: Thank you, before it was always fetches data from first table content of pack id 00086 now it was changing correctly and i have i have learn how fetch data by basing more one condition in select clearly.

Comment: @ dimitre Novatchev:   can you brief about why and when we have to use positon =1 coz i was very confused with that please

Comment: @pravz: `[1]` is a shorthand for `[position() = 1]`. More generally, `[some-integer-type-expression]` is a shorthand for `[position() = some-integer-type-expression]`. The case when you must use the longer form is when it isn't possible for the XSLT processor to know that the type of the expression inside the predicate is integer (but you can guarantee this). For example: `books[$bookNumber]` Here only you know that `$bookNumber` must be an integer, however in general it may have any vallue, such as `'Hello world'`. In all such cases, the XSLT processor evaluates the boolean value of the expr.